# Не обновляется свойство в компоненте Vue

Tags: vue.js, компоненты

Есть родительский компонент, в котором строится таблица при помощи данных полученных из БД при помощи использования такого хука:

```
created: function () {this.getPacts();},
```

код метода `getPacts` такой:

```
getPacts: function () {
  axios
   .get('/pact/get-pacts', {timeout: 2000})
   .then(response => {
     this.loadData = response.data.data
    })
    .catch(error => {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
    })
  },
```

свойство `this.loadData` прописано так:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    loadData: [],
    operators: [],
    isActiveDeletePactModal: false,
    isActiveAddPactModal: false,
    isActiveUpdatePactModal: false,
    indexDeletedPact: 0,
    indexUpdatedPact: 0,
   }
 },
```

Есть дочерний компонент - модальное окно. Используется для записи данных в БД. Мне нужно, чтобы после закрытия модального окна, отправлялся запрос в БД, для обновления таблицы в родительском элементе. Я сделал генерацию события при закрытии модального окна и в родительском компоненте прописал отлов этого события, но он не отрабатывает.

Вот так прописано в дочернем компонете:

```
methods: {
  closeModal: function () {
     this.$emit('reload');
     this.$parent.isActiveAddPactModal = false;
     this.clearAllData();
    },
  }
```

Вот так прописано в родительском компоненте:

```
<h2 class="main-color active-element" @reload="getPacts">Перелік договорів</h2>
```

В итоге: метод `getPacts` даже не вызывается.

**В чем может быть проблема?**

Comment: Пока для решения вопроса отслеживаю флаг состояния модального окна через watch, если он меняется на false, запускаю обновление родительского компонента. Вот так     watch: {
        isActiveAddPactModal: function (val) {
            if (val === false) {
                this.getPacts();
            }
        }
    },

Comment: Но вопрос не закрыт. как можно это сделать проще?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно вы неправильно используете метод `closeModal` в дочернем компоненте.
Посмотрите пример реализации подобной задачи в подготовленном для вас примере:
[Пример пользовательского события во Vue](https://codesandbox.io/s/child-parent-event-2fzxv).

При подготовке ответа, использовалась информация из официальной документации `Vue` - [Пользовательские события Vue](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html), [Компоненты Vue](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html).

Comment: Этот вариант отработал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вы отслеживаете событие reload, на нативном тэге h2. У этого тэга нет такого события. Событие которое эммитит дочерние компонент необходимо отслеживать непосредственно на нем.  Если же Вы назвали компонент именем, которое совпадает с именем нативного тэга, то нужно поменять имя